# Mockito with generic method

Tags: java, android, generics, mockito

I am trying to mock a generic method on my class with mockito but when the test code runs i always get a NullPointerException.

This is the class i want to mock.

```
public abstract class MyClass{
      public abstract <T> T find(T t);
}
```

My test code looks something like this.

```
@Mock private MyClass myClass;

public testOnReceive(){
             Mockito.when(
                myClass.find(Mockito.isA(BroadcastReceiver.class))).
                thenReturn(broadcastReceiver);

                myReceiver.onReceive(context,intent);

}
```

And finally the class i am trying to test is an extention of the BroadcastReceiver class and this is the code that i want to test

```
public class MyReceiver extendes BroadcastReceiver{
       public onReceive(Context context , Intent intent){
             ...
             ...
             myClass.find(this);
       }
}
```

The problem is with the mocking of the class. The class actually gets mocked(it is not null) but when the generic method is called then i get a null.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please paste relevant stack trace in pastebin? I don't see result of myClass.find(this) being used in onReceive method, so I am not able to understand if NPE is thrown due to null return by find method or not.

Comment: There is not much information in the stack trace. The test just fails with a NPE when the method to myClass.find is called. This is the top of the stack.

Comment: So, basically you are saying that the same mocked class's non generic methods are working fine while generic ones are not? Have you tested the non generic methods in the same test case?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can specify full code of each snippet. Because it is bit unclear which class is under test and how mocks are being injected into target class. I just tested a similar scenario with test setup and it worked for me. May be you are missing @InjectMocks annotation on the class under test or forget to call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) in test setup method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is similar to what Tim suggested but using a different kind of Answer object.
Although i don't completely understand why but what worked for me was the following.

```
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class , Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

After that i did not need to specify anything about when the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which should work for you, even if you have partial mocking (i.e. for some methods you want the real method to be invoked while sometimes you want the mock):

```
public class AbstractMethodMocker implements Answer<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
    {
        Answer<Object> answer;
        if (isAbstract(invocation.getMethod().getModifiers()))
            answer = RETURNS_DEFAULTS;
        else
            answer = CALLS_REAL_METHODS;
        return answer.answer(invocation);
    }
}

@Test
public void testOnReceive() {
    MyClass clazz = mock(MyClass.class, new AbstractMethodMocker());
    when(clazz.find(any(BroadcastReceiver.class)).thenReturn(broadcastReceiver);
    myReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

[Here is a great blog](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/12/05/mocking-only-abstract-methods-using-mockito-partial-mocking/) which discusses strategies of dealing with abstract classes (and their methods) using the Mockito framework.

Comment: Hi Tim. Unfortunately your solution did not work for me. I still get the same error when the test fails. Somehow the object is not created for the specific generic parameter.